# Integral of $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1+x^2)}}dx}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to solve the following question:

> Evaluate: $$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1+x^2)}}dx}$$

This is an unsolved question in my sample papers book and so I believe it should have an elementary primitive.

But, I don't know how to start this. I want a hint to get started with this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that it has an elementary primitive.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, it has one.

Comment: @rv7 How do you know that it has an elementary primitive since you don't know how to start? Also did you write it correctly?

Comment: You can evaluate the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ and get a nice closed form. I am not sure if it has an elementary primitive.

Comment: @Zacky, it is an unsolved question in my sample papers book and so I believe it should have an elementary primitive. Also, I have checked it many times after I've posted it to make sure it is correct.

Comment: @rv7 This integral doesn't have elementary primitive (use Chebyshev's theorem)

Comment: It seems that an elementary solution doesn't exist, see here $$-\frac{2 \left(x^2-1\right) F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right|-1\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} \sqrt{x}
   \sqrt{x-x^3}}$$

Comment: The substitution $x=\tan t$ reduces the problem to $\int 2^{-1/2}\csc^{1/2} 2t dt$, which is unlikely to be elementary.

Comment: Notice that the asymptotics I added to my answer is very good as soon as $x\gt 3$ for which $0.0014$%

Comment: @J.G. It leads to an ordinary hypergeometric function too. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

We can also express the solution in terms of the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the [Incomplete Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) as I cover [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d):

\begin{align}
I&= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x\left(1 + x^2\right)}}\:dx = \int_0^x \frac{t^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(t^2 + 1 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \:dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left[ B\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{-\frac{1}{2} + 1}{2} , \frac{-\frac{1}{2} + 1}{2} \right) - B\left(\frac{1}{1 + x^2};\frac{1}{2} - \frac{-\frac{1}{2} + 1}{2} , \frac{-\frac{1}{2} + 1}{2} \right) \right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left[ B\left( \frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{4} \right) - B\left(\frac{1}{1 + x^2};\frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{4}  \right) \right] 
\end{align}

Using the [relationship between the Beta function and the Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) we find that:

\begin{equation}
 B\left( \frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{4} \right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\right)} = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{\pi}} 
\end{equation}

Thus our integral $I$ becomes:

\begin{equation}
 I = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x\left(1 + x^2\right)}}\:dx  = \int_0^x \frac{t^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(t^2 + 1 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \:dt = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  - B\left(\frac{1}{1 + x^2};\frac{1}{4} , \frac{1}{4}  \right) \right] 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Several CAS I used for $$I=\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1+x^2)}}}$$ express it as an awful elliptic integral but
it can be "simplified" as $$I=2 \sqrt{x} \,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4};-x^2\right)+C$$ where appears  [the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

If you want an acceptable approximation of it for the integral for $0 \leq x \leq 2$ , you could use the following Padé approximant built at $x=0$

$$2 \sqrt x\,\, \frac{1+\frac{96645617 }{53568140}x^2+\frac{31538874293
  }{31069521200}x^4+\frac{3758605721543 }{20195188780000}x^6+\frac{791037744588979
   }{123594555333600000}x^8} {1+\frac{102002431 }{53568140}x^2+\frac{108481355723
   }{93208563600}x^4+\frac{384016013641 }{1553476060000}x^6+\frac{30608751719
   }{2485561696000}x^8}$$ which is in error of $6.86\times 10^{-6}\text{ %}$ at  $x=1$ but $1.13\times 10^{-2}\text{ %}$ at $x=2$.

For infinitely large values of the upper bound, we can expand the interand and integrate termwise to get
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{ x^{-2 n-\frac{1}{2}}}{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}}$$ which gives the asymptotics and simple ways to approximate the value of the definite integral. For example, using $\color{red}{10}$ terms only in the summation gives for fiteen significant figures
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  x  & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1.0 & \color{blue}{1.85}008944498406 & 1.85407467730137 \\
 1.5 & \color{blue}{2.136962}08793742 & 2.13696267480776 \\
 2.0 & \color{blue}{2.32606419}317845 & 2.32606419421172 \\
 2.5 & \color{blue}{2.46224022503}003 & 2.46224022503732 \\
 3.0 & \color{blue}{2.565720296556}84 & 2.56572029655697 \\
 3.5 & \color{blue}{2.64754771012530} & 2.64754771012530
\end{array}
\right)$$ and all of this being easy to compute since
$$a_n=\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{ x^{-2 n-\frac{1}{2}}}{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}\implies a_{n+1}=-\frac{(2 n+1) (4 n+1)}{2 (n+1) (4 n+5) x^2}\, a_n$$

Comment: You can express it in terms of the Beta and Incomplete Beta Function too:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057298/solving-used-real-based-methods-int-0x-fractk-lefttn-a-rightm-d

Comment: @DavidG. You are right ! I knew your answer in the linked post and ... I did not remember (problem of age for sure); Why don't you write an answer her for this specific case. If you don't want to do it, let me know and I should edit my answer quoting your work. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Claude Leibovici! I hear ya - age does that to a person haha. I will post up my solution.

Answer (score 0):

> This is an unsolved question in my sample papers book and so I believe it should have an elementary primitive.

Well, there is no elementary primitive, because the roots of the cubic under the root are not repeated: $0,i,-i$. It requires an elliptic integral:
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x(1+x^2)}}\,dx=F\left(\cos^{-1}\frac{1-y}{1+y},m=\frac12\right)+C$$
On my side I prefer using the Byrd and Friedman tables rather than a CAS to work out elliptic integrals (the above formula is 239.00). Often the result is cleaner and the parameter $m$ ends up in the classic range of $[0,1]$.